# SSH from different Wifi network?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, jailbreak, ssh

I'm currently at college (living away from home) and my iPod Touch is at home. Its jailbroken and has OpenSSH installed through Saurik's Cydia repo. Is there any way I can SSH to get a theme file that I installed on the phone and pull it to my computer? I can ask my parents to unlock the phone to make sure its connected to Wifi as well as to tell me the Local IP address of the phone as well. What other steps do I need to connect from my computer to my phone?

Short version with no explanations
I want to SSH into my phone from a different wifi network.

Comment: You'll need to allow ssh through your home router - way too much to précis at http://www.howtogeek.com/68061/setup-ssh-on-your-router-for-secure-web-access-from-anywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ask your parents to turn on your iPad and connect it to the local network.
If you have remote administration on your router you'll be able to do the next steps yourself, else you'll need your parents to do it.

1. Login to your router's administration page
2. Get the external IP address of your router (if you can set up dynDNS this will make your life easier in the future)
3. Work out the IP address of your iPad
4. If your router allows you to, it'd be useful to assign it with a static IP address
5. Navigate to the port forwarding page (probably under security or firewall)
6. Configure port 22 (standard for ssh) to forward to your iPad (some routers will allow you to forward it to a MAC address making it doesn't matter if the devices IP address changes)
7. Now, from your computer SSH to the external IP of your router (or dynDNS address if you have that)